# How to write a grammar that accepts the language formed by strings $e^{3n} f g^{2n} h$?

Tags: context-free-grammar

$e^{3n}\: f \: g^{2n}\: h$

n ∈ ℕ∪{0}

For Example:

```
fh

eeefggh

eeeeeefggggh
```

I am stuck at the $e^{3n}$ and $g^{2n}$ part. This is what I have so far:

```
S→EfGh 
E→eE∣ϵ
G→gG∣ϵ
```

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: With your approach, the language could have any number of e unrelated to the number of g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S\rightarrow Th, \;\; T\rightarrow eeeTgg\;\; T\rightarrow f$.

Comment: Thank you. It's much simplier than i thought.